# URL User ID Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, rails-api

How would I make a url go from:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1
```

To a url that is more universal like so:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/users/(id already assumed based on the signed in user)
```

Is there a way I can make the url go to the certain user id without the user actually having to specify the id? Can it be assumed just based on the already signed in user? Clarity on this issue would be great!

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Since you are doing an API a user is usually not signed in across request unless you pass a cookie back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an authentication based in tokens you can use them to find the current user.
The most common approach is to use the route `/me` for that.

```
class Api::V1::CredentialsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  respond_to    :json

  # GET /me.json
  def me
    respond_with current_resource_owner
  end

  private

  # Find the user that owns the access token
  def current_resource_owner
    User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
  end
end
```

The example above is an implementation by using the [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#authenticated-resource-owner) gem.